# Is there a golang sdk equivalent of "gcloud container clusters get-credentials"

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a golang sdk equivalent of:
`gcloud container clusters get-credentials`

I have created a gke cluster using golang sdk `google.golang.org/api/container/v1`. Now I want to obtain the kubeconfig for the created cluster. Is there way in golang to achieve that?

I have explored the `func (r *ProjectsZonesClustersService) Get(projectId string, zone string, clusterId string) *ProjectsZonesClustersGetCall`. But this returns the complete cluster configuration not the kubeconfig.

I expect to get the kubeconfig of the gke cluster using golang google container sdk.

Answer (score 1):

The GKE API does not have a call that outputs a kubeconfig file (or fragment). The specific processing between fetching a full cluster definition and updating the kubeconfig file are implemented in python in the gcloud tooling. It isn't part of the Go SDK so you'd need to implement it yourself.

You can also try using `kubectl config set-credentials` (see [this](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes.github.io/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set-credentials.md))  and/or see if you can vendor the libraries that implement that function if you want to do it programmatically.