# Deploying services in GKE k8s cluster using Golang k8s client

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm able to create a GKE cluster using the golang container lib [here](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/container/v1). 
Now for my golang k8s client to be able to deploy my k8s deployment files there, I need to get the kubeconfig from the GKE cluster. However I can't find the relevant api for that in the **container** lib above. Can anyone please point out what am I missing ?

Comment: There seems to be a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191900/is-there-a-golang-sdk-equivalent-of-gcloud-container-clusters-get-credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Subhash suggestion I am posting the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191900/is-there-a-golang-sdk-equivalent-of-gcloud-container-clusters-get-credentials/56192493#56192493) question:

> The GKE API does not have a call that outputs a kubeconfig file (or
>   fragment). The specific processing between fetching a full cluster
>   definition and updating the kubeconfig file are implemented in python
>   in the gcloud tooling. It isn't part of the Go SDK so you'd need to
>   implement it yourself.
>
> You can also try using `kubectl config set-credentials` (see
>   [this](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes.github.io/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set-credentials.md))  and/or see if you can vendor the libraries that implement
>   that function if you want to do it programmatically.

Comment: I'm using `kubectl config use-context CONTEXT_NAME [options]`. It works better for my issue. Thanks